# Real time javascript to server connection

Tags: javascript

I know that you can use AJAX to call php/mysql, a server-side language with javascript. However, it's not fast enough to be used in realtime applications.

When I say real time I mean that the time it takes for the server to respond should be below 100ms.

Any way of doing this? AJAX calls are a bit too slow.

Libraries are okay, and if there are solutions with other languages let me know.

Comment: Two thoughts... First it depends on your LINE speed. Second, you should consider a server-side executable instead of PHP. So you're looking at a native app like Pascal or C/C++

Comment: How would the javascript access this server side executable? Is it fast enough to be realtime?

Comment: How are the machines connected together? Although building a "real-time" system with these components is ridiculous, I'm surprised that average delay would be so much for a one-machine setup.

Comment: Well, it's going to be AJAX if you're expecting interaction without a page reload. On the other hand, depending on your application, OS, etc., you can decide on various client-end options like Flash, ActiveX or a browser plug-in. But if your end-user is going to be restricted, I'd stick to Javascript. And if it's AJAX, you're only scoring with regards to the speed of the program on the server. This is because PHP is first compiled each time you call the page. But in the case of a native app, you're saving this time.

Comment: Just for your info, I use a similar technique to shutdown my Linux server on the LAN. I didn't want to give the end user access to shutdown the server from the server's terminal. So I put a program in C on the server and it's called from the user's browser. So the last person to leave office clicks the link and off goes the server. That's only an example but your case may be different.

Comment: @itsols, The parse time of PHP is the least of the problem, in almost every case.  There is no reason to use what you propose as the first step towards speeding things up.  Even if you did, there's always HipHop, which you can use long before switching languages/technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend looking into [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/).  It will use Websockets where available, and falls back nicely to other transports when needed.

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution! I'm looking into it at the moment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In ASP.NET there is SignalR which I've tested and I found amazing. Using SignalR you can create applications for real time purposes. Your client can be javascript, web application, desktop application, or even console application.

For more info see https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR

Answer (score 0):

If you consider .NET I would look at XSockets http://xsockets.net - A mature framework that has been using websockets since 2009.

Regards
Uffe